# insert data to temporary table in sql 2008

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpt
(
ID INT
,sName varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpt VALUES (1,'ran')
INSERT INTO #tmpt VALUES (2,'pan')
INSERT INTO #tmpt VALUES (3,'fan')
INSERT INTO #tmpt VALUES (4,'gan')
```

This type of insert does not work. Can you help

Comment: You're missing `;` between the queries

Comment: @Barmar, depending on the dms you can omit the `;`

Comment: Appears to work for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3bc8 -- can you explain -- "does not work"?

Comment: If by "does not work" you mean results don't persist - well it is a *temporary* table after all

Comment: i get this error   Invalid object name #tmpt

Comment: i got the issue.. It was the issue with create table IS NULL check. Thanks for all the help